# PHP or Apache url to folder faker?

Tags: php, apache

When i go to a URL like this: http://www.something.com/store/

How do i get PHP or Apache to load from a different folder?

For example:

Instead of:
    /www/store/

I want to load from:
    /www/stuff/plugin/store/ instead.

Is there a way in PHP scripting or apache .htaccess?
i have tried using header, but there is no way to account for all possible files type.
Any solution that work with : RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]?

Any help appreciated!
Any idea also appreciated!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Alias? Thank You! I tried mod rewrite, that did not work too well... now I am now hoping for a PHP scripting alternative as well.

Comment: 'mod rewrite' is the php way. Apache has to come first

Comment: Well, i was hoping for a dynamic PHP version first, honestly.

Comment: can not be done with pure php, apache(or other web server) does the path routing

Comment: Well, for known file it is possible with header, such as jpg and css. but i guess there is no way to do it without php writing to htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

So, what i did was use Alias in .htaccess to solve this problem.

In the end, it require PHP to search for tag in .htaccess and write or rewrite for dynamic SEO url.
This allow any CMS to redirect script query to the right folder/directory in question.

Once again, thank you to everyone who commented on this post!